# Will tag referencing commits unreachable from any branch be lost?

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

I worked on my project, on branch `branch`. Then I reverted using

```
git revert tag-name
```

Then I did some progress and committed. When I try to push I get this error:

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   not have locally

I do not want to lose my progress before the revert, but want to remove from `branch` the commits made after, keeping them available for future reference just under the `1.00.00rcXX` tag.

I created a clone of the repository, tagged head of `branch` there, and rewound `branch` to the revert commit:

```
git tag -a 1.00.00rcXX -m message
git reset --hard HEAD~1 # remove last commit from current branch
```

Now I want to force push my changes back to my original repository, so all the commit ahead of `branch` will be lost.

**Will my tag be lost too, as it is based on commits unreachable from `branch`?**

Comment: @Palec I do want to lose all the commits ahead of my revert. And I also want to save them on tag for future reference. But I certainly do not want to merge any commit after ahead of my revert, this is why I am forcing push.

Comment: Reading your question again, I think I finally get what you were trying to get across. You made the revert and subsequent changes in your repository and then cloned this repository only to create the `1.00.00rcXX` tag in the clone. Is that correct?

Comment: "The tag will keep those commits alive" this answering my question. Are you sure that it is true?

Comment: I posted an answer. Now I’m thinking about editing your Q so that it makes sense without this comment thread. Is this course of events equivalent to what happened to you? `git clone 'git://some.remote/repos' project` and there `git checkout branch; git revert tag-name; some-work; git tag -a 1.00.00rcXX -m message; git reset --hard HEAD~5` and now `branch` is the same as immediately after the `git revert tag-name`. In this moment you are asking if it is safe to force-push `branch` without losing the history referenced by the `1.00.00rcXX` tag.

Comment: Edited your question to make more sense to future visitors. Feel free to clarify if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unreachability and garbage collection

Only really unreachable commits can be garbage-collected, and thus lost forever.

Quoting [`man gitglossary`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_unreachable_object):

> unreachable object
>
> An object which is not reachable from a branch, tag, or any other reference.

As long as the tag exists, the part of history it links to is considered reachable and thus not garbage-collected. The tag keeps those commits “alive”.

## Pushing the tag and force-pushing the branch is safe

Git tries to prevent you from making non-fast-forward changes in any branch. You have to pass the `-f` option to `git push` to perform push after resetting (rewinding) the branch. If you keep in mind the [implications of overwriting history](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase), you can push both the tag referencing original state of the branch and the new head of the branch and you will lose nothing.

Just run this:

```
git push --tags
git push -f origin your-rewound-branch
```

## Better use branch instead of a tag

By the way, using tag for such a thing is probably not a good idea. Probably you will want to delete that dead-end part of development history someday, which you should not do with tags. Using a branch (head) instead of a tag is more suitable for such a purpose. Just use (maybe with a more descriptive name)

```
git branch 1.00.00rcXX
```

instead of

```
git tag -a 1.00.00rcXX -m message
```